# Failing to import transformers.models.t5.modeling_flax_t5

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

The following error occurs:
`RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.t5.modeling_flax_t5 because of the following error (look up to see its traceback): module 'jax.numpy' has no attribute 'DeviceArray'`

when I try to run this command on python:

`model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("luqh/ClinicalT5-base", from_flax=True)`

I tried to update my tokenizers and others:

```
transformers             4.31.0.dev0
torch                    2.0.0
tokenizers               0.13.3
```

Comment: did you try to install/reinstall jax
`pip install jax` ?

Comment: yes, both jax and jaxlib (0.4.14) were reinstalled